# pip install package TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python-2.7, pip, gpio

When I want to use *pip* to install a package named RPi.GPIO in my windows 10 computer, this error appear. I also tried to download and install this package manually(python setup.py install) but didn't work.How can I fix this problem?

```
    running build_py

    creating build

    creating build\lib.win32-2.7

    creating build\lib.win32-2.7\RPi

    copying RPi\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\RPi

    running build_ext

    building 'RPi.GPIO' extension

    Traceback (most recent call last):

      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

      File"c:\users\chenz\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_chenz\RPi.GPIO\setup.py",  line 47, in <module>

    ext_modules      = [Extension('RPi.GPIO', ['source/py_gpio.c', 'source/c_gpio.c', 'source/cpuinfo.c', 'source/event_gpio.c', 'source/soft_pwm.c', 'source/py_pwm.c', 'source/common.c', 'source/constants.c'])])

  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\core.py", line 151, in setup

    dist.run_commands()

  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands

    self.run_command(cmd)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command

    cmd_obj.run()

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run

    return orig.install.run(self)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 563, in run

    self.run_command('build')

  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 326, in run_command

    self.distribution.run_command(command)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command

    cmd_obj.run()

  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 127, in run

    self.run_command(cmd_name)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 326, in run_command

    self.distribution.run_command(command)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command

    cmd_obj.run()

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_ext.py", line 54, in run

    _build_ext.run(self)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 337, in run

    self.build_extensions()

  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 446, in build_extensions

    self.build_extension(ext)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_ext.py", line 187, in build_extension

    _build_ext.build_extension(self, ext)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 496, in build_extension

    depends=ext.depends)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 473, in compile

    self.initialize()

  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 383, in initialize

    vc_env = query_vcvarsall(VERSION, plat_spec)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 266, in query_vcvarsall

    vcvarsall = find_vcvarsall(version)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 243, in find_vcvarsall

    toolskey = "VS0.f0COMNTOOLS" % version

TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Comment: Just look at the line that's failing: where's `version` supposed to be going in `"VS0.f0COMNTOOLS"`? This is what it ought to look like: https://bitbucket.org/carljm/python-distutils/src/48c42eeaee4410d76675b637bcd401b8919ff19a/msvc9compiler.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#msvc9compiler.py-223 Which versions of Python/distutils are you using?

Comment: Thanks! I use ActivePython 2.7.10.12.Does this version of distutils cause this error?Maybe I can edit the msvc9compiler.py to fix this.

Comment: I don't know, I've never used ActivePython and don't know what distutils they use. Consider raising this with the maintainers.

Comment: This is helpful enough.Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix [error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat#), I edited msvc9compiler.py 's line 243 and missed a '%'.
Let's forget this stupid question.
By the way, I download a Visual C++ 2008 Express Edition to fix the error:Unable to find vcvarsall.bat. And it's work.